Ways to know if my dependent variables are correlated?
I have 7 dependent variables (photochemical parameters such as: Y(II), NPQ, Y(NPQ), Y(NO), qN, qP and qL) and I need to know if they are correlated in order to see the possibility of doing a multivariate analysis (all variables only take values between 0 to 1). Any idea please?
Thanks
So far I have only explored graphically, but I need some test to run in r.
